# Database indexing in code first approach

Tags: sql, entity-framework

As far as ive learnt from other post, one major advantage of code first approach is that we need not look back into database which is a must in model/db first approaches.

In my scenario the database needs a lot of indexing and is it right to go for code first approach rather than db first approach.?

Also if indexing is not available in code first and ive to do indexing seperately, is'nt the flexibility of using code first approach is lost.??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into the `[Index]` attribute. There are annotations available for code first. In my experience, you can set up an entire database using the code first approach.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Entity framewok from version 6.1 support indexes.

```
public class DepartmentMaster  
{  
[Key]  
public int DepartmentId { get; set; }  
public string Code { get; set; }  
[MaxLength(100)]  
[Index(“IX_Name_DepartmentMaster”, IsClustered = false)]  
public string Name { get; set; }  
}
```